# i dont know why but it crashing me at startActivity(StartIntent); i try to sand a ArrayList of the class User to ScenedActivity

Tags: android-studio

the cod crash on startActivity(StartIntent);
i dont know why i start us android studio and i try code that i had in my head
and i dont know why but it crashing me at startActivity(StartIntent); i try to sand a ArrayList of the class User to ScenedActivity

```
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
User Dan = new User("dan","ali","game12",1234);
static int cod;
final int num = 10;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    users.add(Dan);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText Cod = findViewById(R.id.Cod);
    Button NextActivity = findViewById(R.id.NextActivity);
    NextActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!isEmpty(Cod))//if the text box is empty pot 0 in cod
                cod = Integer.parseInt(Cod.getText().toString());
            else if (isEmpty(Cod))
                cod = 0;
            if (cod == num ) {// if the cod that pot in EditText = my cod(num) go on
                Intent StartIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScenedActivity.class);
                StartIntent.putExtra("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER", "Hi");//sand to scened activity string "hi"
                StartIntent.putExtra("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER1",users);//sand to scened activity ArrayList of User
                startActivity(StartIntent);

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error worng code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//sand 
            }
        }
    });
}
private boolean isEmpty(EditText etText) {//check if text box is empty
    if (etText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: i think that it is this:(it is not all i cant sand the all Error)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 12754
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.example.myapplication.User@6f3d786

(thanks.)